# Generating table with SUM columns based on different conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, subquery, aggregates

I am fairly new to SQL and I am struggling with generating a table with multiple aggregates based on certain filters.

My temporary able has 3 columns **where an individual is unique by Category ID AND Customer ID (i.e. there can be multiple identical Customer IDs across categories)**.

| Category ID | Customer ID | Number of Purchases |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | A | 4 |
| X | B | 10 |
| X | C | 2 |
| Y | A | 2 |
| Y | E | 6 |
| Z | A | 10 |
| Z | C | 5 |
| Z | D | 7 |

The output table I am looking for is basically 4 columns: **grouped by category ID** identifying **total number of customers who have at least 3 purchases**, **customers who have at least 5 purchases** as well as **total purchases across all customers within that category**. The output table would look like this:

| Category_ID | Total_Customers_3 | Total_Customers_5 | Total_Purchases |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | 2 | 1 | 16 |
| Y | 1 | 1 | 8 |
| Z | 3 | 3 | 22 |

When I input the following code, I get the correct total purchases column per category but the total number of customers who had at least 3 purchases per category is incorrect as the aggregates are identical across all categories.

My code:

```
SELECT table.categoryID AS Category_ID
       (SELECT COUNT (table.customerID)
               FROM table
               WHERE table.purchases >=3) AS Total_Customers_3,
       (SELECT COUNT (table.customerID)
               FROM table
               WHERE table.purchases >=5) AS Total_Customers_5,
       SUM (table.purchases) AS Total_Purchases,
FROM table
GROUP BY Category_ID, Total_Customers_3, Total_Customers_5,
```

(P.S When I try to just GROUP BY Category_ID, I get an ERROR that syntax is incorrect because I have sub-queries in my SELECT statement.

The *incorrect table* (i.e. same number of total customers meeting the condition across all categories) I get looks like:

| Category_ID | Total_Customers_3 | Total_Customers_5 | Total_Purchases |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | 2 | 1 | 16 |
| Y | 2 | 1 | 8 |
| Z | 2 | 1 | 22 |

**Update: I should have included this in the original question but I am actually looking to generate 2 columns in the same about total number of customers based on 2 conditions - one for customers with at least 3 purchases and another column for customers with at least 5 customers.**

Answer (score 2):

Aggregate by category, and the use conditional aggregation to get the counts and totals.

```sql
SELECT
    Category_ID,
    SUM(purchases >= 3) Total_Customers_3,
    SUM(CASE WHEN purchases >= 3 THEN purchases ELSE 0 END) AS Num_Purchases_3,
    SUM(purchases >= 5) Total_Customers_5,
    SUM(CASE WHEN purchases >= 5 THEN purchases ELSE 0 END) AS Num_Purchases_5
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Category_ID;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: Thanks, Tim. What if I need to generate 2 columns for Total_Customers based on 2 different conditions in the same table? So purchases >=3 along with purchases >= 5. I left out that but I realize that changes the entire approach where I am failing.

Comment: That's not what you asked, nor what I answered.  You may use conditional aggregation, something like `SUM(CASE WHEN purchases >= 5 THEN purchase ELSE 0 END)` ... I won't update my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I am still getting used to using stack overflow. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @AL0290 I have answered your second question above, have a look.  Please do _not_ change your question dramatically after others have answered.  The answers already there were probably tested and took some effort, and your changing the question forces everyone to answer a _new_ question all over again.